Episode where man and woman become conjoined after eating skin
I remember watching a TV episode in the early-mid 90s where a man and a woman couple wake up conjoined at the shoulder after the man eats a slice of the womans skin.
I remember a scene in a shower where she slices a sliver off and gives it to the man.
They then try and operate on themselves using hand tools without luck.
They shut themselves in the house at the end and I think the narrator says they never leave the house again.
The final scene was them walking up a staircase in a white bed robe.
I believe it was an episode of a British anthology series, but could be mistaken. It was English language.
